# Can I check the NFTs in a virtual machine wallet in remix?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, nft, remix

I am learning about NFT minting by using remix to run test code on testnets. Now the function seems to be working as the ETH balance is reduced by the amount of mint price I set, but I can't check the NFTs the given wallet was holding. Is there a way to view it somewhere to check if the NFT is successfully minted?

UPDATE: I see that people can use test nets with their own wallet to receive those NFTs and view them on platforms like Opensea. But is it possible to do the same with VM?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are using a virtual machine or not, should not have the ability to use Remix or access any testnets. So it is possible. Remix and Ethereum wallets use [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) to communicate with [JSON-RPC nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) that allow your wallets, transactions and other to function.

Comment: I mean the VM option of the Remix though. For now I am using test net accounts to view the NFT I minted, but I also would like to check if it is possible to view the NFT minted by accounts in Remix VM as I won't need to get Eth from testnet every time I am trying to test if that's achievable.